# Google finance's date range selection without the graph itself

Tags: gwt, charts, google-visualization

I need an elegant way to let users select a date range, what I would like to do is use the AnnotatedTimeline that Google Finance uses and hide the graph output.  According to the javadoc for AnnotatedTimline http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/AnnotatedTimeLine.html I can listen to date range selection choices but I cannot figure out a way to "hide" the chart itself.

Does anybody have a suggestion?